# Checking an array for descending order

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm

I am writing code to check if my array is in ascending or descending order. If the boolean 'ascending' is true, then I check if it is ascending. If it is false, then I check for descending. I need help checking whether the array is descending or not... I have the code to check ascending which is written below:

```
protected boolean isSorted(boolean ascending) {
    boolean result = false; 

    if (ascending) { 
        for (int i=0;i<data.length-1;i++) {
            if(data[i] < data[i+1]) {
                result = true;
            } else if(data[i] > data[i+1]) {
                result = false;
            }
        }
    } else {
        //code to check for descending order
    }
}
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The first part of the `if` (the "ascending" check)  is wrong, it should be:

```
for (int i = 0; i < data.length-1; i++) {
    if (data[i] > data[i+1]) {
        return false;
    }
}
return true;
```

Conversely, the descending check should be (and notice that it's enough to change the direction of the comparison operator):

```
for (int i = 0; i < data.length-1; i++) {
    if (data[i] < data[i+1]) {
        return false;
    }
}
return true;
```

In both cases, you have to break out of the loop as soon as you find a *single* pair of numbers that do not hold the ascending-or-descending property, and only return `true` after the loop exits.

Comment: both implementation will fail. You need to loop up until data.length-2.

Comment: @Korhan on second thought: no, it's correct as it is. check your indexes.

Comment: sorry, yep looks nice. Thought you had i <= data.length-1

Answer (score 3):

You can cheat and do it in one loop if you like and remove one addition:

```
protected boolean isSorted(boolean ascending) {
    for (int i = 1; i < data.length; i++) {
        if (data[i-1] == data[i]) {
            continue;
        }
        if ((data[i-1] > data[i]) == ascending) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

NOTE: I am building on the code by @OscarLopez so upvote his if you upvote mine.

Comment: +1 nice answer and nice sportsmanship :) a bit of nitpicking: the `if (data[i-1] == data[i])` condition is unnecessary, and you can safely remove it

Comment: That `==` part applies when its descending. If they are equal, the `>` would be `false` which is `== false` and the function would return false without that part.

Answer (score 0):

To check if `ArrayList<Integer>` is in descending order try this:

```
boolean isSorted(ArrayList<Integer> list){
 boolean sorted = true;

      for (int i = 1; i < list.size(); i++) {
         if (list.get(i-1) >= (list.get(i)) ) {

             sorted = true;
             } else {

                 return false;

             } // if else ends


          } // for "i" ends

      return sorted;
}
```