# How do I send user inputted integers to a linked list in Java?

Tags: java, list, int

I am trying to write code to have users input positive integers and have them sent to a linked list. The users input should end after entering a negative number. Furthermore, I am having issues writing an isSorted boolean method that will return true if the linked list is sorted in increasing order and false otherwise.

Here is the only code I have so far

```
import java.util.*;
public class List {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Please type positive integers one by one separated by a space.");
    System.out.println("When you are done, please type a negative integer.");
    int num = input.nextInt();

    }


    public boolean isSorted(){


        if(){ 
        return true;
        }
        else{
        return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You *really* shouldn't call your class `List`.  There's already an interface by that name in Java (`java.util.List`), and you're going to cause a lot of confusion with your name, *especially* since you're importing `java.util.*`.

Comment: Your question is a little vague as to what exactly you're trying to do.  When you say you are trying to send integers to a linked list, do you mean you want to store them in a `java.util.LinkedList`?  The fact that you've declared a class called `List` indicates that perhaps you are trying to write your own linked list.  You haven't written enough code to make it clear what your goal is.

Comment: Answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18005437/checking-an-array-for-descending-order

Answer (score 2):

```
public void input() {
    System.out.println("Please type positive integers one by one separated by a space.");
    System.out.println("When you are done, please type a negative integer.");

    LinkedList<Integer> ll = new LinkedList<>();

    //System.in.available()

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    int num;
    while ( input.hasNextInt() ) {
        int i = input.nextInt();
        if (i >= 0) {
            ll.add(i);
        }
    }

    System.out.println(ll+" <-- ll"); //TODO remove debugging code

    System.out.println(isSortedAccending(ll)+" <-- isSortedAccending(ll)");//TODO
}
```

This works by returning `false` the moment something is found out of order.

```
public static boolean isSortedAccending(List<Integer> list){
    if (list.size() < 2) {
        return true;
    }

    Integer previous = list.get(0);
    for (Integer next : list) {
        if (previous > next) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Outputs:

```
Please type positive integers one by one separated by a space.
When you are done, please type a negative integer.
1
2
3
-1
[1, 2, 3] <-- ll
true <-- isSortedAccending(ll)
```

`isSortedDecending()` looks exactly the same except it uses `<`.

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class NumberListing {

   public static void main(String[] args) {
       Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
       System.out.println("Please type positive integers one by one    separated by a space.");
       System.out.println("When you are done, please type a negative integer.");
       int num = input.nextInt();   
       LinkedList<Integer> list = new LinkedList<Integer>();
       while(num > 0){

           list.add(num);
           num = input.nextInt();
       }

       if(isSorted(list)){
           System.out.println("The list is sorted");
      } else{
           System.out.println("The list is not sorted");
       }
   }


       public static boolean isSorted(LinkedList<Integer> list){
           boolean done = false;
           boolean sorted = true;
           for(int i = 1; i < list.size() && !done  ; i++){
                if(list.get(i) < list.get(i-1)){
                    done = true;
                   sorted = false;
               }
           }
           return sorted;
       }
  }
```

Should be fairly simple. While the number you intake is greater than 0, store the number in a list and get the next one from the console.

After that, loop through the list starting with index 1 to check that each current number is greater than the previous  number. I added an early exit so the loop quits anytime a number that is less than the previous number. this means it is unordered and we don't care about the rest.

However, if you're trying to create your own linked list that creates a lot more code and I would suggest looking in a text book or something of the sort to help.

Answer (score 0):

You can put your int's in a container(LinkedList) by using the wrapper class Integer for int. The normal int is a standard primitive type and can not be used by containers, as containers can only work with objects of a class.

```
LinkedList<Integer> list = new LinkedList();
```

As for the isSorted method, you could iterate through the list and check if the current value is higher or equal to the previous value.

```
int prevValue = 0;

for(int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++){
    if(!list.get(i) >= prevValue){
        return false;
    }
    prevValue = list.get(i);
}
return true;
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to read the next line as a String, split that line, and walk through the list of elements of that line, adding the positive elements to a LinkedList as you go. Make sure you store your scanner. You'll want to use `nextLine`, not `nextInt`.

```
import java.util.*;
public class List {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Please type positive integers one by one separated by a space.");
    System.out.println("When you are done, please type a negative integer.");
    String line = input.nextLine();
    String[] integers = line.split(" ");

    LinkedList ll = new LinkedList<Integer>();
    for (int i = 0; i < integers.length; i++)
    {
        if (Integer.parseInt(integers[i]) > 0)
            ll.add(integers[i]);
    }

    System.out.println(isSorted(ll));
    input.close();
 }
```

Then, just use a simple comparison function for LinkedList to check if it's sorted:

```
public static <T extends Comparable<T>> boolean isSorted(LinkedList<T> iterable)
    {
        Iterator<T> iter = iterable.iterator();

        if (!iter.hasNext()) {
                return true;
            }
         T t = iter.next();
            while (iter.hasNext()) {
                T t2 = iter.next();
                if (t.compareTo(t2) > 0) {
                    return false;
                }
                t = t2;
            }
            return true;
    }
```